# Creating a new task with ExchangeService on Office 365

Tags: c#, .net-core, office365, exchangewebservices

All the old [ExchangeService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice?view=exchange-ews-api) [examples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Exchange-2013-Create-tasks-39b938ea) are looking great:

```
exchangeService = new ExchangeService();
exchangeServie.Credentials = new WebCredentials('user', 'pass');
exchangeService.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
var task = new Task(exchangeService);
task.Subject = "...";
task.Body = "..";
task.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Tasks);
```

But it does not work with Office 365, it throws exception:

> *"An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Std/1916"*

The first part of the exception is probably from a Dictionary, the "Key..." part is unknown.

Exception's source is *"System.Private.CoreLib"*.

What is the correct implementation to create a new task in Exchange/Office 365 Online?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand the problem. The snippets you provided as is should not cause that problem, so that would mean you have excluded important details.

Comment: Thanks, creating ExchangeService instance added

Answer (score 1):

As @Nkosi says I'm not sure the error can be traced to the sample you have provided. However I can say what would be my answer to the question *What is the correct implementation to create a new task in Exchange/Office 365 Online?*

I would look at the sample: *Office 365: Create a task in Exchange Online*.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Online-Set-up-a-d5207541/view/SourceCode#content

Have a look at the method `CreateTask(string subject, string message,DateTime startDate)`. I think it is very similar to your example but I don't know how your `ExchangeService` is set up. I would try to get the code working with the code below and then implement it in your solution.

Models:

```
/// <summary>
/// Task creator credentials.
/// </summary>
public class UserModel
{
    public string TaskCreatorEmailID { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

}

/// <summary>
/// Task entity along with attributes.
/// </summary>
public class TaskModel
{
    public string TaskTitle { get; set; }
    public string TaskMessage { get; set; }
    public DateTime TaskStartDate { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// User's task collection along with user information.
/// </summary>
public class UserTasksModel
{
    public UserModel User { get; set; }
    public TaskModel NewTask { get; set; }
    public List<TaskModel> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

Calling methods:

```
//Create TaskManager instance with user credentials.
TaskManager taskManager = new TaskManager(model.User.TaskCreatorEmailID, model.User.Password);

//Call create task method
taskManager.CreateTask(model.NewTask.TaskTitle, model.NewTask.TaskMessage, model.NewTask.TaskStartDate);
```

TaskManager:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace ManagingTasksUsingEWS
{
    public class TaskManager
    {
        private  ExchangeService _service;
        private  string _taskCreatorEmailID;
        private  string _password;
        public ExchangeService Service;


        public TaskManager(string taskCreatorEmailID,string password)
        {
            _taskCreatorEmailID = taskCreatorEmailID;
            _password = password;
            Service = GetExchangeService();
        }

        private ExchangeService GetExchangeService()
        {
            if (_service == null)
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
                _service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
                _service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(_taskCreatorEmailID, _password);
                _service.TraceEnabled = true;
                _service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
                _service.AutodiscoverUrl(_taskCreatorEmailID, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
            }
            return _service;
        }

        private static bool CertificateValidationCallBack(
                            object sender,
                            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
                            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
                            System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            // If the certificate is a valid, signed certificate, return true.
            if (sslPolicyErrors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                return true;
            }

            // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
            if ((sslPolicyErrors & System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) != 0)
            {
                if (chain != null && chain.ChainStatus != null)
                {
                    foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
                    {
                        if ((certificate.Subject == certificate.Issuer) &&
                           (status.Status == System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
                        {
                            // Self-signed certificates with an untrusted root are valid. 
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (status.Status != System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
                            {
                                // If there are any other errors in the certificate chain, the certificate is invalid,
                                // so the method returns false.
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // When processing reaches this line, the only errors in the certificate chain are 
                // untrusted root errors for self-signed certificates. These certificates are valid
                // for default Exchange server installations, so return true.
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // In all other cases, return false.
                return false;
            }
        }

        private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
        {
            // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
            bool result = false;

            Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

            // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
            // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
            // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
            if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
            {
                result = true;
            }
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The method will create task in "Tasks" folder
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="subject">Subject of the task</param>
        /// <param name="message">Message body of the task</param>
        /// <param name="startDate">Start date of the task</param>
        /// 
        public  void CreateTask(string subject, string message,DateTime startDate)
        {
            // Instaniate the Task object.
            Task task = new Task(Service);

            // Assign the subject, body and start date of the new task.
            task.Subject = subject;
            task.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.Text,message);
            task.StartDate = startDate;

            // Create the new task in the Tasks folder.
            task.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Tasks);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TaskManager class is just a wrapper around the problem, the 'CreateTask' method calls the same code as mine. I'll try it of course (maybe some ExchangeSettings are different) and I'll report back

Comment: @boj Yes but as you say they connect differently. Given that it is official Microsoft documentation/code it should work. :)

Comment: "Given that it is official Microsoft documentation/code" - it means nothing:) Every other functions (listing tasks, getting mail list information etc.) works without any exception.

Comment: @boj That information was not provided in the original question. Does the user have the correct privileges? Do you have an all access admin user you can test with? Does any create/update/delete method work?

Comment: Yes, any other function (ie. listing tasks, listing mail list members etc.) works perfectly. This is the only method that - as far I know - throws exception. And of course I need that method:)

Comment: Very frustrating. There is no exception when saving a new task - but it does *NOT* creates a new task! I've debuged it and seems to be working...but only seems:(

Comment: @boj Could you try downloading the following project and see if it works? Try not to edit any code. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Online-Set-up-a-d5207541/file/76610/7/Office%20365%20Create%20a%20task%20in%20Exchange%20Online.zip

Comment: Thank you but please do not forget that I'm working with .NET Core and this is a .NET 4.x(?) based solution.

Comment: @boj Sure, but it would still be nice to see if it works. If it does work then simply start migrating the code from that project.

Comment: Yeah, but it don't work. There is no starting point to migrate to Core cause of the API is the same in .NET 4.x and .NET Core - but Core skips creating the task.

Comment: @boj So it worked in the project I sent? Does the NuGet packages used show compatibility with .Net Core or .Net Standard?

Comment: @boj Try using the NuGet package Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices 2.2.0. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices/. If you are satisfied with my help or if it helped you along the way please award the bounty. It will be wasted in 5 hours otherwise.